# Пропали зависимости проектов в Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Недавно поставил  *Visual Studio  2017 Community*. Ставил с сайта *Microsoft*.
Вчера открываю проект, а  в нем - только те зависимости и ссылки на сборки, которые качал через *NuGet*. Остального нет. Естественно, ни один стандартный класс, начиная с *object*, студия не видит, в проекте 500 ошибок.
Где подтянуть руками -  тоже не нашел.
Переустановка студии (просто снес через "Программы и компоненты") ничего не дала.
Собственно вопрос: Как бороться с этой бедой?

Дополнительная информация:

1. Проект `ASP.Net Core`
2. На компе стоят  2  студии:  2013  и 17. Какое-то время было 3, но потом 15-ю снес.  После сноса еще неделю студия работала нормально.
3. Открытие любого другого проекта - ситуация аналогичная.
4. Студия  2013 работает нормально

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы такое:
В меню VS:
 Сервис -> Параметры -> Менеджер пакетов NuGet -> проставить галочки в чекбоксах "Разрешить NuGet  скачивать отсутствующие пакеты"  и на всякий случай ставил галочку в чекбоксе "Автоматически проверять отсутствие пакетов при сборке в Visual Studio".
После этого, в меню при клике правой кнопкой мыши по проекту появляется пункт "Восстановить пакеты NuGet"
В решении помогла вот эта ссылка: http://www.xavierdecoster.com/migrate-away-from-msbuild-based-nuget-package-restore

Почему слетают пакеты  при загрузке -  я так и не разобрался.